# What is the benefit of @emotion/react over @emotion/css for a React project?

Tags: reactjs, emotion

If I install `emotion/css` then the API is nice and clear:

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@emotion/css": "^11.1.3",
```

React component:

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

const someStyle = css`
    display: none;
`

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div className={someStyle} />
  );
}
```

However according to the docs you should install `@emotion/react`:
https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
```

Now the API is a lot more messy:

```
import React from "react";
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/react";

const someStyle = css`
  display: none;
`;

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div css={someStyle} />
  );
}
```

Not only do you need a comment `/** @jsx jsx */`, but you also have to import `jsx` even though it's not used. In my IDE this means I get a lint warning by my React import.

What is the benefit of the recommended way? Im tempted to ignore the documentation and do it the old way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `jsx` pragma/import is required because the `css` prop is provided by a wrapper around `React.createElement` - without that transform being applied, the `css` prop would not work.

That said, including it in every file is tedious - that's why there is a [babel plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop) that does it for you.

```
{
  "presets": ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"]
}
```

With regards to the benefits of using this method over the stock `emotion` package, the docs list some on the page you linked:

> - CSS prop support
>
>   - Similar to the style prop but adds support for nested selectors, media queries, and auto-prefixing.
>   - Allows developers to skip the styled API abstraction and style components and elements directly.
>   - The css prop also accepts a function that is called with your theme as an argument allowing developers easy access to common and customizable values.
>   - Reduces boilerplate when composing components and styled with emotion.
> - Server side rendering with zero configuration.
> - Theming works out of the box.
> - ESLint plugins available to ensure proper patterns and configuration are set.

Comment: It's not my original question but FYI that solution doesn't appear to work (at least as is).

Answer (score 7):

Both are valid and each approach has its benefits:

`emotion/css`:

- use vanilla react `className` prop
- no custom jsx parser
- no babel config or file pragmas
- no extra typescript config
- generate class names outside of react components

`emotion/react`:

- zero config for `@emotion/cache`
- easy server side rendering
- easy access to theme through css function

More resources

- [React vs Vanilla Essay](https://colinhacks.com/essays/emotion-core-vs-vanilla-emotion)

  - Outline of pros of vanilla over react
- [Github issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1883)

  - Great respectful github discussion between essay author and emotion dev